# python...creating a variable to pass as file name

Tags: python

I have a number of files that I want to look at and I would like to label each one based on a set of variable, e.g.,...

```
location = 'home'
source_system = 'Sys_'
date = '20160608'
file_name = location+source_system+date
print(file_name)

-> homeSys_20160608
```

...based on the file_name I want to use that to label the dataframe, so something like...

```
file_name = sqlContext.read.parquet(file_path)
```

I have the file_path defined elsewhere.

What happens when I try this is the dataframe is now named file_path not homeSys_20160608 which is what the variable originally was.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Basically I am wondering if there is a way to create a data frame based on variables. I want to create multiple data frames each with a different name so I can analyze them in one python notebook. Each data frame would have the same structure but different data populated.

Comment: This is a bad idea - you should [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Use a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining 'location+source_system+date' without any filesystem delimiters.

your string will look like this: `homeSys_20160608`

You want it to be this, I believe: `home/Sys_20160608`

You can either manually put one in like so:

```
file_name = location + '/' + source_system + date
```

Or use the `os` module:

```
file_name = location + os.path.sep + source_system + date
```

in order for it to work on windows and Linux.

Comment: Using `os.path.join` is an option as well, and IMHO clearer

Comment: True, but I since two of the strings need to be joined directly and then `os.join`ed to the third I though this would be cleaner than `filename = os.path.join(location, source_system + date )`